# Lazy loading properties, @property decorator

Tags: python

I want to implement lazy loaded properties in a class. I thought it is easy and implemented it like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if not self._bar:
            self._bar = longTimeLoadedData()
        return self._bar
```

But now I am surprised that after **init** the _bar variable contains the longTimeLoadedData even Foo.bar was never called... Could someone explain the behaviour to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please give us a complete example that demonstrates this.

Comment: Use `is not None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it already works as what you want:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if not self._bar:
            self._bar = 1
        return self._bar


f = Foo()

print(f._bar) # None
f.bar
print(f._bar) # 1
```